# Is there a way to stop a NpgsqlConnection from being in waiting state and meanwhile ensure to not loose any notifications when waiting?

Tags: c#, postgresql, notifications, database-connection, npgsqlconnection

In PostgreSql, I wrote generic code to be notify on table update.

Doing so, I have to wait for the connection. Not waiting, I receive no notification from the Database. So I wait like this:

```
conn.Wait(Timeout.Infinite);
```

I could have used Wait without any parameter in a loop be I was afraid to miss some notifications by concurrency. For example when 2 notifications enter simultanously, when wait is called without parameter and is released by receiving the first notification, we can miss the second one (before returning in the wait state). So I used "Timeout.Infinite".

To stop th connection from another thread, I tried to close it with:

```
conn.Close()
```

But I receive an exception:

```
Npgsql.NpgsqlOperationInProgressException: 'The connection is already in state 'Waiting''
```

**So the question is :**

Is there any way to stop the connection from being in waiting state and meanwhile ensure to not loose any notifications when waiting?

Note: I think (only my opinion) it is missing a CancellationToken from the PostgreSql "Connection.Wait" function. We should be able to cancel the waiting either when waiting for the next change.

Comment: Use `await WaitAsync` with an `async Task` function, and pass the `CancellationToken` in. https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.html#Npgsql_NpgsqlConnection_WaitAsync_System_Int32_CancellationToken_

Comment: Please do not post images of code or data, only paste as text.

Comment: @Charlieface, thank you very much for both (how to better use S.O. and the answer). I will write the Exception as code in few minutes. I will take a look to your answer. I expected that both Wait and WaitAsync would have the same parameters but it does not sems to be the same. Thanks a lot. It seems to be the expected answer.

Comment: I will check tomorrow and will get back to you thanks!

Comment: @Charlieface, I does not work: _dbConnection.WaitAsync(Timeout.Infinite, _cts.Token).Wait(); ... That code never wait for any events. It continue either if there is no update in the database. It should work but it does not.

Comment: You need to use `await` with async code. And are you cancelling `_cts`?

Comment: I'm not on a UI thread either not in ASP.NET

Comment: @Charlieface, It works now with your proposition: "WaitAsync" which enable me to use a CancellationToken". Thanks a lot. I don't understand why there is no CancelationToken in the other one but...). There were some other tricks that I had to do on the Connection but your answer was exactly what I was looking for.  So, I wonder  =>  Can you write an answer ? I will accept it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`WaitAsync`](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.html#Npgsql_NpgsqlConnection_WaitAsync_CancellationToken_) function, which accepts a `CancellationToken`.

```cs
await conn.WaitAsync(someToken);
```

Obviously this must be done in an `async` function, which should never be called using `.Wait` or `.Result` as you could deadlock. Instead do [async all the way down](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming).